# How can I get rid of the error "you did not select file to upload" in CodeIgniter?

Tags: javascript, ajax, codeigniter

I am implementing a CodeIgniter application in HMVC. I have my application working well in mvc but I needed to move it to hmvc. Each time I click submit, I get an error that "You did not select file to upload". Here below is my view;

upload.php

```
<form data-action="<?= base_url('client/do_upload') ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="ajax_form">
    <label class="control-label">Repalce Image</label>
    <input type="file" name="image"><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Below is my controller

```
class client extends CI_Controller
{
   public function _do_upload(){
        $config['upload_path'] = 'assets/images/';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg';
        $config['max_size'] = 2000;
        $config['max_width'] = 1500;
        $config['max_height'] = 1500;

        $this->upload->initialize($config);

        if (!$this->upload->do_upload('image')) {
            exit(json_encode(array('status'=>0,'msg'=>$this->upload->display_errors())));
        } else {
            $data = array('image_metadata' => $this->upload->data());

            $this->load->view('files/result', $data);
        }

}
```

I am using an javascript pop up to display the errors. When I use the form class to open the form, it works as follows;

```
<?= form_open_multipart('client/_do_upload') ?>
```

But the problem with this is that my custom js uses the form id to display the errors as the popup

But when I pass additional attributes like the id as

```
<?= form_open_multipart('client/_do_upload', ['id'=>'ajax_form']) ?>
```

Or

```
<?= form_open_multipart('client/_do_upload','id'='ajax_form') ?>
```

I also get the error.

Comment: did you load the library? `$this->load->library('upload', $config);`

Comment: You use the URI  `client/do_upload` in the data-action form attribute, but the function is named `_do_upload()`. Initial underscore in the function name is usually only used (and sometimes preserved) for private methods. Instead rename it to `do_upload()` and try again. Still the same error?

Comment: @Michael K, I changed as you have proposed but still the same error